# Create matrix of complex coordinates in MATLAB without loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix of complex coordinates, so that it contains all combinations of the real and imaginary numbers that I specify. For example:

```
    Re = 0:0.5:1; % Real numbers
    Im = 0:0.5:1; % Imaginary numbers

    C = zeros(length(Re),length(Im)); % Pre-allocate matrix
    for i = 1:length(Re)
        for j = 1:length(Im)
            C(i,j) = complex(Re(i),Im(j)); % Real part + Imaginary part
        end
    end
```

The results are:

```
    Re =
       0    0.5000    1.0000

    Im =
       0    0.5000    1.0000

    C =
      0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.5000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i
      0.5000 + 0.0000i   0.5000 + 0.5000i   0.5000 + 1.0000i
      1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.5000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i
```

When I make the real and imaginary vectors larger, this loop takes a considerable amount of time. Is there a faster way to create a matrix like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with the `@plus` handle:

```
>> re = 0:0.5:1;
>> im = 0:0.5:1;
>> bsxfun(@plus,re(:),im(:).'*1i)

ans =

   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.5000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i
   0.5000 + 0.0000i   0.5000 + 0.5000i   0.5000 + 1.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.5000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out for a 10,000x10,000 matrix, and my code took 12.9 seconds, while yours took 1.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is much faster, but assuming they're the same length:

```
Reals = [0:0.5:1]; % Real numbers
Imags = [0:0.5:1]; % Imaginary numbers

C = Reals * eye(length(Reals)) + eye(length(Imags)) * Imags.' * i
```

Comment: I tried running the code, but it said that the matrix dimensions don't agree.

Comment: I edited to add a period before the apostrophe; if that doesn't work, create the first and second halves separately and check that they are the same dimensions. If not, you should be able to work backwards to see what is causing dimension issues. Remember that left vs right matrix multiplication makes a difference, so don't change the order

Comment: The first half (real half) is a horizontal vector, and the 2nd half is a vertical vector, so they won't add up. How should they combine to make a matrix with both length and width?